# iTunes popup on song change

Tags: macos, mac, itunes

All of a sudden my iMac has started showing a popup notification in the middle of the screen every time a song changes. I'm not sure what's changed. But I don't want them.

[image: iTunes popup]

I checked iTunes's preferences and didn't see anything, though admittedly I often overlook things. I thought maybe it was Growl which I installed years ago, but it doesn't look like it as it wasn't running and wasn't configured for iTunes notifications anyways.

Where are these popup notifications coming from, and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Is that QuickSilver perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was QuickSilver. Going to its preferences panel and unchecking "Display Track Notifications" got rid of the popups.

[image: QuickSilver preferences]

Thanks @slhck!

Answer (score 1):

With all the updates, it can now be found within iTunes, under Preferences *(which is listed under "File")* and simply unchecked.

[image]